# How to clean up elastic scale databases

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

While testing Elastic Scale I wanted to start over a couple of times without deleting the complete databases. Since this might save you some time I though I would share the [following SQL](https://gist.github.com/marcelbuesing/0cbb05c2a03b554a8c96) to cleanup databases used for Elastic Scale Shards and the ShardMapsManager.